# Change data and processResults context for Select2 in Angular2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, jquery-select2

I am using Select2 in my Angular2 app and I need to use some class properties in the data and processResults. However these contexts are not the class context:

```
export class DefaultFormInputSelectComponent {

    @Input() private validator;

    private select2Options() {

        return {
            ajax: {
                url: 'api',
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                data: this.ajaxData,
                processResults: this.ajaxProcessResults
            }
        }

    };

    ajaxData = function(params) {

        // this variable is not in DefaultFormInputSelectComponent context

        this.validator; // returns undefined, but it is not in DefaultFormInputSelectComponent context

    }

    ajaxProcessResults = function(data) {
        // same issue as ajaxData
    }

}
```

I tried to add `context: this` in `ajax` property but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read a little about typescript, you will find out that inside classes you should not use the `function` keyword, and also binding callbacks like that will cause the `this` context to be placed to the function. You should use the arrow function notation to create your function or use `bind`. Or you can use an anonymous arrow function wrapper :) you decide what you like best:

```
export class DefaultFormInputSelectComponent {

    @Input() private validator;

    private select2Options(): any {
        return {
            ajax: {
                url: 'api',
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                data: this.ajaxData,
                processResults: this.ajaxProcessResults.bind(this),
                anotherCallback: (data) => {
                    this.processAnother(data);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private ajaxData: Function = (params: any): void => {
        console.log(this); //DefaultFormInputSelectComponent 
    };

    private ajaxProcessResults(data: any): void {
        console.log(this); //DefaultFormInputSelectComponent 
    }

    private processAnother(data: any): void {
        console.log(this); //DefaultFormInputSelectComponent 
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that. Actually I'm just learning about TS, Angular, etc... Thank you very much! Worked like a charm!

Comment: That's what we're here for ;). Glad i could help